# can phonegap(cordova) run javascript background on android and ios?

Tags: android, cordova, background, android-activity

> I use phonegap on android, since it base on activity, so it often start again from onCreate. how can I make my code run background, can javascript run background?

Answer (score 1):

No. Remember Javascript runs in browser, and therefore *needs* the browser to work.

Look into creating your own plugin to interact with native code:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide